# R-codes in LaTeX using listings

Tags: indentation, r, code

I use the package `listings` to include R-codes in my project.

Unfortunately, it produces (sometimes, but not always) a hanging indent in the pdf document.

Is there a possibility to erase this hanging indent (I want only justification in my print, see also a more conrete example what I meant below the code)?

Here is an extract of my LaTeX file using the `listing` package:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=R]
#read.in is a function which reads in the picture 
#as 620x872X3 matrix 
#(#pixels in height x #pixels in width x #channels)
#RGB channels are used for reading in .png picture

read.in<-function(pic){
  require("png")
  datpng <-img <- readPNG(system.file("img", pic , package="png"))
  dat<-apply(datpng, c(1,2), sum)


  #define grid with 10 x 14 boxes on the picture, 
    #which used later in the algorithm
  nrow<-10
  ncol<-14
  sizer<-dim(dat)[2]/nrow
  sizec<-dim(dat)[1]/ncol

  #arr is array containig precisely the boxes 
    #with handwritten numbers as subarrays a[,,k], 
  #k ranges from 1 to 10*14 
    #= number of boxes containing precisely one digits
  arr<- array(0,c(sizec, sizer, nrow*ncol))
  k<- 1

  for (i in 1:ncol){
    for (j in 1:nrow){
      arr[,,k]<-dat[(i-1)*sizec+1:sizec,(j-1)*sizer + 1:sizer]
      k<-k+1
    }
  }


  #Reshape 167x165x140-array arr into the 27555x140-array arra, 
  #hence arra[,k] are exactly the data corresponding to one scanned digit,
    #where k ranges from 1 to 140=#boxes.
  arra<-arr
  dim(arra)<-c(prod(dim(arr)[1:2]), dim(arr)[3])
  arra<-t(arra)


  #generate data frame for classification 
  classes<-c(rep(0:9, each=10),0:9, 0:9, 0:9, 0:9)
  ar<-data.frame(nr=factor(c(classes)), arra)

  return(ar)
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

We see that in the line starting with `#define grid...` and the following line starting with `#which...` there is a hanging indent, but I want actually that it looks like (in the sense of indent) the line starting with `require("png")...` and `datpng....`. Here we see that there is no haning indent, but there is only justification used.

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't replicate a "hanging indent". Could you elaborate what you mean?

Comment: @Werner Sorry I did only give an extract of my code, which may not replicate a haning indent. I edit my post with my whole code and now one sees that e.g. in the line starting with "#width...." there is a haning indent. I just want something as in the first 8 lines of my code.

Comment: Firstly, there is no line `#width`, only `#with`, `#which` and `#where`... Secondly, the indentation provided is what is replicated by [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings). It's not done on purpose, it's because you supplied that input. Could you provide a picture of the current output and then also what the desired output should look like (even if you have to replicate it in another environment)?

Comment: I'm sorry I meant #with. See the edit in my post.